# I got the MissingTemplate error but not knowing the reason

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I access the page `https://lazyair.co/specials/2015-09-25-02` correctly,

And I do have the template `specials.html.haml`

But it still show me the `ActionView::MissingTemplate`

How could it happen ? any direction ? Thanks

## controller

```
def specials
  @specials = Special.all
end
```

## exception

```
An ActionView::MissingTemplate occurred in welcome#specials:

  Missing template welcome/specials, application/specials with {:locale=>[:"zh-TW", :zh], :formats=>["image/webp", "image/*"], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :haml, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
-------------------------------
Request:
-------------------------------

  * URL        : https://lazyair.co/specials/2015-09-25-02
  * HTTP Method: GET
  * Parameters : {"controller"=>"welcome", "action"=>"specials", "token"=>"2015-09-25-02"}
  * Process: 7573
```

Comment: What folder is `specials.html.haml` located in?

Comment: how does the route look like for `specials`?

Comment: @ahmacleod located at app/views/welcome

Comment: @KMRakibulIslam `      get 'specials/(:token)' => 'welcome#specials'
      get 'specials' => 'welcome#specials'`

Comment: can you try my answer: `get '/specials' => 'welcome#specials', :format => /(?:|html|json)/` and see if that fixes your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict your route to some predefined formats like this:

```
get 'specials/(:token)' => 'welcome#specials', :format => :html
get 'specials' => 'welcome#specials', :format => :html
```

Sometimes this solution works. But, if this does not fix your issue, then try to explicitly respond to the format in your controller action:

```
  def specials
    @specials = Special.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { }
    end
  end
```

Comment: actually,i only allow the html format for this page :)

Comment: so if you this: `get 'specials' => 'welcome#specials', :format => :html`, still you are getting the same error?

Answer (score 0):

Because your question lacks some of the finer details, here's what I'd do:

```
#app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
    def index
       @specials = Special.all
    end
    def show
       @specials = Special.find params[:id]
    end
end

#app/views/welcome/show.html.haml
...

#config/routes.rb
resources :welcome, path: "specials", only: [:show] #-> url.com/specials/:id
```

I understand this changes the method name (I'd rather use conventional routing than make special method names). It should give you the structure required to negate the error.

---

Further, if you're using this in some sort of "deal" app, you'll want to do the following:

```
#app/controllers/specials_controller.rb
class SpecialsController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @specials = Special.all
   end
end

#app/views/specials/index.html.haml
<% @specials.each do |special| %>
    <%= special.x %>
<% end %>
```